# Tokens for apps in AppExchange for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange

I created an app in Django for Marketing Cloud and I would like to understand something about apps in AppExchange. How do they use client ID or client secret or JWT secret when it is downloaded in a Marketing Cloud instance via AppExchange? For example, now I use my own Installed Package to retrieve information from my Marketing Cloud instance but how is it handled when another user installs it via AppExchange?

Thanks for your help,
Selim

Answer (score 0):

I have the same qustion and I had a call with Marketing Cloud Support team regarding this.
If You are using Web Application API integration type after instalation client Id and client secret will not be changed but if you are using Server-to-Server it will be changed